# SMTP Gmail not working

Tags: email, smtp

Around mid day 7/19 my emails stopped sending. Found out today that my Gmail account created just for the server was disabled. After a few hoops was able to get the Gmail account working again. But EE 2.6.1 still is not sending.

Could Gmail change some settings?

I was using
tls://smtp.gmail.com:465  and port 587 to get EE to use a gmail account.

But at this point I think Gmail changed or is no longer allowing this to work.

Anyone have any insight?

thanks Mike

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i just needed to give it some time after I reactivated the gmail account.